# A Kohan married to a Convert Blessing the People

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, birchas-kohanim

May a Kohan who is married to a convert bless the People (Birkhat HaKohanim?)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35539/15256

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73780/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No a kohen is not allowed to perform birkat kohanim if he is married to a convert or even if he is no longer married to one until he swears not to do it again as the shulchan aruch paskens in OC 128:40

> "כהן שנשא גרושה לא ישא את כפיו ואין נוהגין בו קדושה אפי' לקרות בתורה
>   ראשון ואפילו גרשה או מתה פסול עד שידור הנאה על דעת רבים מהנשים שהוא
>   אסור בהם:
>
> A kohen that married a divorcée may not perform the priestly blessing,
>   and we do not treat him with sanctification, even to call him up to
>   the Torah first. And even if he divorced her or she dies, he is
>   invalid [as a kohen] until he swears off all benefit, in the public's
>   discretion, from women who are forbidden to him."

The Mishna Brurah then comments

> כהן שנשא גרושה וכו' - וה"ה חללה וזונה או חלוצה ומה שנתבאר בסמוך שאין
>   שאר עבירות מונעים נ"כ היינו דוקא בעבירות שאין שאר הכהנים מוזהרים יותר
>   מישראל אבל במה שהכהנים מוזהרים יותר מישראל שקדושת כהנים גרם לו והוא
>   חיללו לפיכך פסול מדרבנן לכל דבר כהונה עד שידור ע"ד רבים וכו'
>
> He says that the law also applies to a chalala or a zona or a chalutza
>   and a convert falls under that law as halacha assumes that the nations
>   of the world are promiscous and therefore a convert is automatically a
>   zona. **Therefore if a cohen is married to a convert he can not go up to
>   the duchan.**

Answer (score 2):

Vayikra 21:7....... ויקרא כא ז

**אִשָּׁ֨ה זֹנָ֤ה** וַחֲלָלָה֙ לֹ֣א יִקָּ֔חוּ וְאִשָּׁ֛ה גְּרוּשָׁ֥ה מֵאִישָׁ֖הּ לֹ֣א יִקָּ֑חוּ כִּֽי־קָדֹ֥שׁ ה֖וּא לֵאלֹקיו׃

They (*Kohanim*) shall not marry a *woman defiled by harlotry*, nor shall they marry one divorced from her husband. For they are holy to their G-d

Gemara Yevamos 61a ....... גמרא יבמות סא א

וחכמים אומרים אין **זונה** אלא **גיורת** ומשוחררת ושנבעלה בעילת זנות:

And the Rabbis say: The only women in the category of *zona*, who are therefore forbidden to a priest, are a **female convert**, a freed maidservant...
.
.

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 128:40......שולחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן קכח סעיף מ

כהן שנשא גרושה לא ישא כפיו ... ואפילו גירשה או מתה פסול עד שידור הנאה על דעת רבים מהנשים שהוא אסור בהם:

A Cohen who married a woman who was divorced may not [bless the people (*Birkhat Kohanim*)]... And even if he divorces her or she died he is still *posul* (invalid for *Birkhat HaKohanim*) until he takes a public vow of non-benefit from all women which he is forbidden to them.

Mishna Brurah (ibid 147)..... (משנה ברורה (שם ס"ק קמז

כהן שנשא גרושה וכו' - וה"ה חללה וזונה ... במה שהכהנים מוזהרים יותר מישראל שקדושת כהנים גרם לו והוא חיללו לפיכך פסול מדרבנן לכל דבר כהונה עד שידור ע"ד רבים וכו':

So too [If he marries] a *challala* or a *Zona* (see Above)... [any] which Kohanim are warned against [marrying] more than an Israelite, which the holiness of his *Kehunah* caused it [The prohibition to marry her], and he defiled [this holiness], He is therefore rabbinicaly *posul* (invalid) for anything pertaining to *Kohanim * until he takes a public vow etc.

Comment: This would be a great answer if you could elaborate on the logic behind MB's ruling (which is not present in Magen Avraham) instead of listing the sources without comments and formatting.

Comment: This answer is also useful as it supplies more information on the Birkat HaKohanim. Thank you.